# We're sorry, but something went wrong Heroku

Tags: heroku

Don't start app at Heroku.
Migrate I was do, but it don`t work anyway... Please help my anyone

```
2015-07-17T08:27:11.996879+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2015-07-17T08:27:11.996906+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:15906
2015-07-17T08:27:11.996909+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h for more startup options
2015-07-17T08:27:11.996910+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-17T08:27:16.038259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-17T08:27:15.924000+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.11.3 starting...
2015-07-17T08:27:15.924095+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16 
2015-07-17T08:27:15.924199+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2015-07-17T08:27:15.924281+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:15906
2015-07-17T08:27:18.702571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-eyrie-5960.herokuapp.com request_id=7976700d-bee7-4e6f-b20a-67d60a5d5e8a fwd="176.104.8.251" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=210ms status=500 bytes=1669
2015-07-17T08:27:18.819798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-eyrie-5960.herokuapp.com request_id=23341143-bd39-46ed-a48a-736533558ccd fwd="176.104.8.251" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143`
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from your app's code. However, your app is sending it's logs to the local filesystem, which means you don't see the exception in heroku logs.

You would need to configure your app to send logs to STDOUT or STDERR to be able to see them.
You can add the [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem to your app, which will change your configuration to do just that.

Once you have added this gem to your app and redeployed it, the raised exception should show in your logs and you can fix in your app's code.